# How to enter full screen mode in Flutter web app

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

Is there a way of making a flutter web app enter fullscreen mode (hide addressbar, tabsbar and taskbar)? Or is there a way of programmatically pressing F11?

I've tried...

```dart
@override
void dispose() {
  SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays(SystemUiOverlay.values);
  super.dispose();
}

@override
initState() {
  SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([]);
  super.initState();
}
```

but it didn't work in the web app (I wasn't expecting it to)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You might try this:

```dart
import 'dart:html';

void goFullScreen() {
  document.documentElement.requestFullscreen();
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Abion47 it works, but the app can no longer start on emulator because of 'dart:html' import

Comment: @MohamedDernoun This question is specifically for Flutter for Web. Don't try to use this code in Flutter for Mobile/Desktop, as it will not work and there is no purpose.

Comment: I resolved this by using universal_html which contain all dart:html functionalities with more facilities.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work anymore in iPhone, Safari

Comment: @Damandroid It never worked on Safari on iPhone. The browser environment on iOS has much stricter restrictions on what elements can become fullscreen (basically only videos), and as far as I know, Apple has no intentions for that to change any time soon.

Answer (score 20):

If somebody (like me) wants to exit the fullscreen and struggles to find how:

```
void exitFullScreen() {
 document.exitFullscreen();
}
```

Hope that's useful.

Answer (score 0):

**2023 new answer for FLUTTER PWA:**

If you are building a "PWA": Progessive web app, you can, in the manifest.json file generated by flutter after building for web (I mean, after running the `flutter build web` command) edit the "display" property and change it from "standalone" to "fullscreen", this will make your flutter web app enter fullscreen mode (hide addressbar, tabsbar and taskbar) by default (on init),

**manifest.json** example:

```
 {
      "name": "Example",
      "short_name": "Ex",
      "start_url": ".",
      "display": "fullscreen",
      "background_color": "#000000",
      "theme_color": "#000000",
      "description": "Tu Hogar inteligente",
      "orientation": "portrait-primary",
      "prefer_related_applications": false,
  }
```

more info about manifest.json [HERE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Manifest)

Now, if you want to do to toggle the fullscreen programmatically, you can apply @Abion47 answer, in addition with the kIsweb (if your app is also mobile or desktop) and the universal html package - because the older html package now limits your app for only being web, so you have to use the **universal_html** package in order for it to be a multiplatform app-:

```
    import 'package:universal_html/html.dart'
    import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart' show kIsWeb;
    
    if(kIsweb){
       document.documentElement.requestFullscreen();
    } else {
       //mobile or desktop functionalities
    }
```

More info about the unversal_html [HERE](https://pub.dev/packages/universal_html)

EDIT: You can check the fullscreen API compatibility table [HERE](https://caniuse.com/fullscreen) for the different browsers.